# using visio to automate drawing diagram with c# - can't set custom properties

Tags: c#, visio

I have data I am grabbing from a database, and I want to use those values to populate properties on shapes on a visio diagram.  I open my own template, and display shapes on the sheet with no problem.  My server icon has custom properties such as "manufacturer", "network", etc.  When I print out the custom properties for each shape, I get the following output:

Shape = server Label = Manufacturer Value = 0

etc.  This is all correct since I haven't set any values yet.  When I go to set the values, using the code in the Visio 2003 SDK (SettingACustomProperty.cs) I get an error that "this shape does not have a custom property with the universal name of Manufacturer" - yet printing out the custom properties clearly shows it does (as does looking at the shapeSheet once the shape is drawn in Visio). I've inserted to how I call SettingACustomProperty.  Can someone help me figure out what I need to do to insert values into my custom properties on a shape?

Here is how I am calling the code (for testing purposes I have inserted strings myself):

```
  string keyword = "Manufacturer";
  string manuValue = "\"Dell\"";

  string three = SettingACustomProperty.SetCustomPropertyFormula(visioStarShape, keyword, manuValue);
```

Comment: It'll help if you can provide a link to a small sample file that exhibits this problem. I tried some code to set custom properties and everything worked so it could be something specific with your document or the stencils in the document.

Comment: saveenr - here is what I was trying, but this looks as though I was referencing the labels, not the actual universal name -
[code]

Comment: @saveenr - can you post a sample of how you changed a universal name for a custom property of a shape?

Answer (score 2):

Visio custom properties have three different concepts which can be considered a name.

The first is the label. This is what you generally see in the user interface and is stored in the label cell in the custom property row in the shapesheet. The label is generally not used to access the custom property programmatically.

The second is the row name. This is the name you will see when looking at the custom property row in the shapesheet. It will appear to before the other cells in the row and be prefixed with "Prop." This is the accessed through automaton using the [Name property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff767719.aspx) of the custom property row .

The final row name is the universal name. The universal name exists primarily to allow code find specific Visio objects by name even after the name has been changes when the object is localized, i.e. the name have been translated.  The universal name can be accessed using the [NameU property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766420.aspx) of the custom property row. To learn more about universal names see [Using Universal Names and Syntax to Localize Your Visio Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168460%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

When you call SetCustomPropertyFormula the second argument must be the universal name. This is because internally  SetCustomPropertyFormula uses [get_CellsU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff768120.aspx) which finds a custom property cell using the universal name of the row.  I suspect that you are either using the label or the row name, not the universal name, when calling SetCustomPropertyFormula.

If you are using the label you need to switch to using the universal name.

If you are using the name then it no longer matches the universal name. This may happen is some circumstances when you rename the row. You could find out the universal name and then use it in your code. The VBA immediate window is often an easy way to get the NameU property of a row. Alternatively you could update the shape or the master it was instantiated from to set the NameU property equal to the Name property and then you will avoid this confusion (until you rename the row).

Comment: That makes sense - I was trying to set the universal name but really referencing the label.  

When printing out universal names of rows, I noticed that a fair number of them have names such as "R23", "G87".  Is there any way to change this in my template?

Comment: You can update the masters in the stencils you are using to set the NameU equal to the Name. If you are editing masters remember to use [Master.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766060.aspx)  and [Master.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766772.aspx).

Comment: Does anyone have sample code I could see?  I've printed out the universal names using the NameU function, then tried setting the value using those names, and it still tells me there are no cells with that name...  Also, how do I update the NameU property via Visio itself?  I'm opening the same stencil over and over so don't want to have change these things programmatically if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Kathy: You can find out the name you need to use

```
Debug.Print visioStarShape.Section(visSectionProp).Row(0).NameU
```

Add "Prop." before this name to use it in your code.

Alternatively, with the shape selected, you can show the ShapeSheet by clicking this button in the developer toolbox

[image: Show ShapeSheet button]

You see something like this. Look for the Custom Properties section where you see the labels and the name of your properties:

[image]

Then, you use this name to refer to the property (that's your keyword string).

```
keyword = """Prop.CustProp1"""

or....

keyword = "\"Prop.CustProp1"\"
```

Still, you don't need the SettingACustomProperty.cs file, since you can reference all the cells in the shape's sheet from your VBA code.
It is possible for you to get or set the formula in them.

See if this serves your purpose. It is an answer I've just posted in Office Techcenter:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c837db4c-b90c-4500-b8ae-8d36efca44b6/can-i-apply-custom-property-sets-from-vba-in-visio-2003

Since my system is spanish, I've changed the stencil's and master's names by guess. But the important methods are AddSection, AddNamedRow and especially for you the .Formula one (FormulaForce is the same, but it works even with cells protected with the GUARD function).

Good luck. I'm in love with Visio 2003 (I wish my company had bought Visio 2010, though) :D

```
'Set the value for the property: vsoShape is an object referencing the shape
vsoShape.Cells("Prop.CustProp1").FormulaU = """Hello"""
vsoShape.Cells("Prop.CustProp2").FormulaU = 2556
```

The type of CustProp1 is string, and that of CustProp2 is number.

Regards,